# How to migrate from MOCK API to real API (Angular)

Tags: reactjs, angular, amazon-dynamodb

I am new to Angular, and trying to connect this sample app to my API gateway, which is a ContactApp.
Currently it works on mock API and I want to use an actual api server. I have done all the steps from this [website](https://sanderknape.com/2017/10/creating-a-serverless-api-using-aws-api-gateway-and-dynamodb/) but it seems like a wrong approach, It didn't work. Can someone explain how I should configure it?

here is the request call for getContacts

```
getContacts(): Observable<Contact[]>
{
    return this._httpClient.get<Contact[]>('api/apps/contacts/all').pipe(
        tap((contacts) => {
            this._contacts.next(contacts);
            
        })
    );
}
```

and here is the mock api reply:

```
   this._MockApiService
        .onGet('api/apps/contacts/all')
        .reply(() => {

            // Clone the contacts
            const contacts = cloneDeep(this._contacts);


            // Sort the contacts by the name field by default
            contacts.sort((a, b) => a.name.localeCompare(b.name));

            // Return the response
            return [200, contacts];
        });
```

All I need is an explanation of steps I should follow to migrate MOCK API to cloud..or any similar project?

Comment: ```this._httpClient.get<Contact[]>(`${YOUR_BASE_URL}/api/apps/contacts/all`)```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply do this:
On your `.ts` file:

```
//your imports
import { HttpClient, HttpBackend } from "@angular/common/http";

//
export class YourComponent implements OnInit{
contacts:any;
...

//your constructor
constructor(private http: HttpClient)

//initialize the function here
ngOnInit(): void {
    this.getContacts()
}

//your function to get the contacts API data
getContacts(){
 return this.http.get("your API endpoint")
      .subscribe((contacts: any) => {
        this.contacts= response;
      });
    
}
```

then on your `.html` file, bind the data

```
<p *ngFor="let contacts of contacts">{{contacts.name}}</p>
```